# Xtext: Overriding the quickfix to a Reference

Tags: antlr, xtext

I am attempting to detect whether the right hand side of an assignment is a possible hex value as opposed to another variable reference. so that for example

```
myvariable = 2

a = 4
/* the c reference does not exist therefore the user may mean hex C
add in a quickfix to change to 0xc
*/
b = c
/* The user most probably means a hex number therefore add in a quickfix for
converting it to 0xc1234 */
d = c1234
```

So the right hand side can be either (a-f) or (a-z) (a-z|0-9|_)+ which in effect is an ID. There is a quickfix for this when the variable does not exist, it says "change to any other variable that exists". Is there a way to override this and add in an additional option?

EDIT:
I have moved forward from this and made my own custom validation which checks in a while loop whether or not there is a reference as follows:

```
try{
    while(variable != null) {
        variable = variable.reference
    }
catch(Exception e) {
   error("No such reference exists",
         ....
   )
}
```

which throws an exception when variable.reference is accessed since variable is null. However I cant get the name of the reference on the right hand side.
For example:

```
c = 1
a = x
```

Then when accessing the reference x I get a null and I dont know how to get the name 'x'. It seems that xtext has already figured out and resolved the references and I cant find a way to get the name of the reference (not when its resolved)

Is there a way to get the variable name referenced (prior to its resolution)?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.DefaultQuickfixProvider.getResolutionsForLinkingIssue(Issue)